# Cast a string as array in swift (from Parse server)

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

I am making a query to my parse server with a column containing arrays of Integers ("[1,4,5,6,7]") and I would like to use this result in a variable as an array. In what way should I cast this to make sure that this happens?

```
as! [Int]
```

Is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind to do is this:

Given this string:

```
var str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6]"

str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") //This if you have spaces between comas and numbers
let array = str.components(separatedBy: ",").flatMap({ Int($0)})
```

And you will have an array of integers

Hope it will help

Comment: This works! Is it also possible with an array of strings?

Comment: ofc, then you should remove this: .flatMap({ Int($0)})

Answer (score 1):

It is a JSON format, you can parse it:

```
import Foundation

var str = "[1,2,3]"
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)

print(json)

// output:
// [1, 2, 3]
```